# how do i fix ERROR: Failed building wheel for pandas

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, neural-network, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to install the google-colab library but every time I try to install it with pip it says

```
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pandas
Failed to build pandas
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pandas, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

and

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1003 lines of output]
```

and

```
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> pandas
```

I've tried reinstalling pip, upgrading pip, downgrading pip, using pip3, reinstalling pandas by
itself, and upgrading python, I still keep getting this error. Can someone please help?

Comment: I recommend using the [Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual), it's likely to make your life much easier. All packages are installed as precompiled binaries. [Package List](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.8_win-64/). **If you are using Anaconda, do not use `pip` to install packages that exist within the `conda` ecosystem.** Use `conda install package`. Only use `pip` if the package is not available with `conda install`. Using `pip` can potentially wreck your installation because `pip` and `conda` do not manage dependencies in the same way.